# Need help with error after setting permission to save anything in var/www/html?

Tags: permissions, lamp

```
sudo adduser <your username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data(username):www-data(group) /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
```

I had permission problem which was solved and I have edited my question to explain it better.

Comment: adduser creates new users, I'm confused as to exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i want to save files from sublime text in var/www/html directory
and for that i got this solution??

Comment: in var/www/html directory i can't save anything, what should i do, i am  a beginner and can't getting things easily

Comment: Will you open a terminal and type the following commands for me?
'cd /var/www/html' and 
'ls -la'

Comment: Sir i have edited my question after typing the commands you asked to type in temrinal

Comment: Please look at the answer I've provided and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `adduser hafiz www-data` it creates a new user, hafiz and add it to the www-data group. When you type `adduser hafiz harron www-data` you are not using the command correctly.

If you simply want to save files to the /var/www/html directory you just need to make sure that your user has permission to write files so that group. Since /var/www/html is the default webserver directory it should be owned by www-data.

`gpasswd -a YourUserName www-data`

Afterwards logout and back into your computer and you should be able to edit 
those files. This command will add your user to the www-data group. The output from the commands you posted ls -la shows that the /var/www/html page is owned by user www-data and group www-data

`drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data  4096 جولاي 22 21:22 .`

The '.' stands for the current directory.
After you add a user to a group you Must logout and back in in order for it to take effect. You can see what groups you are a part of by typing `groups` in at the command line while your are logged in.

Comment: hafiz@hafiz-HP-1000-Notebook-PC:~$ gpasswd -a hafiz harron
www-data
Usage: gpasswd [option] GROUP

Options:
  -a, --add USER                add USER to GROUP
  -d, --delete USER             remove USER from GROUP
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -Q, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -r, --remove-password         remove the GROUP's password
  -R, --restrict                restrict access to GROUP to its members
  -M, --members USER,...        set the list of members of GROUP
  -A, --administrators ADMIN,...

Comment: set the list of administrators for GROUP
Except for the -A and -M options, the options cannot be combined.

Comment: i am fed up i can't do it :(

Comment: why do you keep typing two users? You are typing hafiz harron, These are two separate arguments that you are giving to the command. instead of your username. Try typing $(whoami) instead of your username in your command. Your command should look like 'gpasswd -a $(whoami) www-data'

Comment: running whoami will output your username, the $( ) will execute the command and put the output in place so it will put your username directly into the command for you.

Comment: @harron Did you get it?

Comment: i have given it +1, but as i am less than 15 repo it doesn't show up :)